# rs.next() returns false in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

the code is login there are entries in my database my also query is working fine but whenever i put any data valid or invalid it just shows email or pass incorrect my rs.next() just returns false. I also verified jdbc connection it works fine. Used mySql databse.

```
package bean;
import java.sql.*;
public class LoginDao {

public static boolean validate(LoginBean bean){
    boolean status=false;
    try{
        Connection con=ConnectionProvider.getCon();

        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from user432 where email=? and pass=?");
        ps.setString(1,bean.getEmail());
        ps.setString(2, bean.getPass());

        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        status=rs.next();

    }catch(Exception e){}
    return status;
}
}
```

Comment: Consider not ignoring errors. Like: put something into that empty catch block. Gnarf.

Comment: so it may be no result set returned! have you considered that ?

Comment: `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Is the password encoded in db or stored as is?

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like to me is that all this method is meant to do is validate the actual existence of a particular User which contains the supplied E-Mail address and Password. Fair enough but you claim that you always get returned **false** from the method. The obvious reason for that would be the fact that your query found no results otherwise `rs.next()` would be **true**.

Well, it could be the extra curly bracket at the end of your method but let's just assume you just goofed there when copy/pasting the code into your post.

It could however be that `bean.getEmail()` and `bean.getPass()` are not supplying what you think it is, I don't know since we can't see the **bean** class. Maybe what you should try is `bean.getEmail().toString()` and `bean.getPass().toString()`.

If your code is producing an actual Exception then you're hiding it by maintaining a empty **catch** block. There's a real good chance that an exception of some sort is thrown and therefore providing a false result from your method but you'll never know what it is since you have nothing in place to view it. You should really have the exception as a **SQLException** rather than just **Exception** but hey, that's not the end of the world, and within the **catch** block you should at least put something, maybe: `System.out.println("What the....sumthin wrong with ma code!!!");` or even better yet: `e.printStackTrace();`.

Curious...is the Database Table name really **user432**? Or is that a User Name?